# Adding recessed LEDs to existing ceiling fan/light circuit - where to tap?

Tags: wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan

I'd like to add a couple 4" recessed LEDs to an existing fan/light circuit in my room.  The fan/light is controlled by a wall switch, and it also has a remote (fan does not turn on if switch is OFF).  I could use some help figuring out how/where to splice the LEDs into.  Does this need to be done in the ceiling box or in the attic?  There are three 'Romex' entering the ceiling box, as pictured.  I believe one goes to the closet, one to the switch, and one to the main (?). I've also attached photos of the fan wiring and switch.  Any help is much appreciated!

[image]
[image]

[image][image]
[image][image: Final result]

Comment: Thanks HoneyDo and Ed Beal.  Wired in parallel as instructed, much better light output in the room now!

Comment: we thank people around here by upvoting and/or accepting their answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to tap the circuit in the ceiling.
To have the switch control the new lights put them in parallel with the fan. You have 3 cables one hot, one to the closet and a switch leg that takes the hot to the switch and returns to the fan. 
Make to turn the breaker off before connecting the new lights and you need a box at each new light location if the fixtures do not have a box as part of the fixture.

Answer (score 1):

Ed Beal has it right but you need to think about how you want to control the lights. If in parallel with the fan any time the fan is on the LEDs will also be on which is okay if that's what you want. So with the wall switch on, the LEDs will be lit. You can turn off the fan with the remote but the LEDs will be on as long as the wall switch is on. In other words you can't have the fan on and the LEDs off.
If the wire gauge is sufficient you can pigtail into the fan light which will be the wires coming out of the wireless receiver going to the light. In that case the LEDs will activate whenever you turn on the fan light with the remote. Just a thought.